# Tetrahedron base inclination and apex location from altitude angles

Tags: geometry

Given a tetrahedron (points A,B,C,D) with equilateral base triangle ABC of unit side length, and knowing the angles from vertical of the lines AD, BD and CD; how can I calculate the angle the base triangle makes with the horizontal plane, and the location of D relative to ABC?

Comment: Off the top of my head: The angles give you three cones with common apex $D$ on which the other vertices must lie. Pick one and try to find a point on it from which you can build a unit equilateral triangle with vertices on the other two cones. There might not be enough constraints for a unique solution.